# Center element in middle of another element-WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, element

I want to create a kind of title by a `TextBox` and a `Line` (**`WPF`**).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="labelTextbox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,1,5,1"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Line  X1="5" X2="5000" VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Gray"/>
    <TextBox Text="Buttons" Style="{StaticResource labelTextbox}"/>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Margin="10" Content="Button A"/>
        <Button Margin="10" Content="Button B" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button Margin="10" Content="Button C" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button Margin="10" Content="Button D" Grid.Row="3"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

The screen looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the line is aligned to the middle row of the grid, but not to the **middle of the text box.**

I tried to put the text box `VerticalAlignment="Center"`, and I tried to remove margin and padding, but nothing helped.

How can I center the line to middle of text box without defining it specifically by location?(Generically so that it will fit any size of line, and any size of text)

Comment: What does it mean `not to the middle of the text box.`? Can you show an image of how it should be, to make it more understandable?

Comment: Since you didn't declare Grid.Row for Line and TextBox both takes Grid.Row = "0" .If you want line in middle set separate row for that and assign row value..if my understanding is wrong,give more details.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev. Line tends to upward (relative to the text box). I guess that it's related to the text size and so the line is not exactly the middle of the text, the question is how to do this?

Comment: @kumar, I don't understand how separate rows will set the line in the middle of the text box.

Comment: middle of the text box means like strike-through ?

Comment: then re order the Line and TextBox in VisualTree as 
 
    <TextBox Text="Buttons" Style="{StaticResource labelTextbox}"/>
<Line  X1="5" X2="5000" VerticalAlignment="Center" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Gray"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try for `Line` set [`UseLayoutRounding="True"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.uselayoutrounding(v=vs.95).aspx):

> Gets or sets a value that determines whether rendering for the object and its visual subtree should use rounding behavior that aligns rendering to whole pixels.

**`Example`**

```
<Line UseLayoutRounding="True"
      X1="5" X2="5000" ... />
```

**`Output`**

`UseLayoutRounding="False"`

[image]

`UseLayoutRounding="True"`

[image]

In this case, `UseLayoutRounding` makes one pixel line in the middle. If you want the `Line` to be crossed out text, then you need to swap the TextBox and Line, but also in this case you need to use `UseLayoutRounding="True"`.